# Use Google Storage without Key and Secret

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

The `AWS S3 cloud service` has been migrated to `Google Storage` (Simple Migration) as well as the database.

See some necessary adjustments, for example, **do you need to adjust any way to use Google Storage without passing a key and an authorization secret**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're asking, there are two answers:

1. If you're asking whether it's possible to make anonymous calls to read and write objects, yes, that's possible.
2. If you're asking whether it's possible to make authenticated calls in a way that doesn't pass auth secrets, you can do that by switching to OAuth2-based authentication.

Both topics are covered in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication